# USPS RateV4 - How do I display the rate object?

Tags: coldfusion, usps

I am using the following code with the [USPS Rate Calculator API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/price-calculators.htm):

```
<cfscript>
variables.RateV4 = variables.usps.RateV4(
                     Service = 'FIRST CLASS',
                     FirstClassMailType = 'LETTER',
                     ZipOrigination = '44106',
                     ZipDestination = '20770',
                     Pounds = '0',
                     Ounces = '3.5',
                     Size = 'Regular'
                   ); 
WriteDump(var="#variables.RateV4#" label="RateV4");
</cfscript>
```

The output looks something like:

```
RateV4 - xml document [long version]
RateV4Response XmlText
           Package  xmltext 
                    .
                    '  
                    Postage  xmltext
                             .
                             .
                             Rate      xmlText 1.06
```

[image: Picture of the XML output]

How do I get the rate object into a simple CF variable? i.e.

```
<cfoutput>#RateV4.Package.Postage.rate.XmlText#</cfoutput>
```

I tried a bunch of formats without success.

Comment: What error do you get with your current attempt?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your top level XML element in the dump.

Now take a look at the code you posted in your question.

Notice anything missing?

You are not using the correct XML 'path' in your code (You left out the top level node in your code).

You could also use [xmlSearch()](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlSearch) to grab the `rate` node.

Comment: <cfoutput>RateV4Reponse.Package.Postage.rate.XmlText#</cfoutput>